# What could cause IE10 to block an iframe when running without compatibility view

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-10

We're experiencing an issue with our site, YouSIMUL8.com. We use this site to allow people to run simulations on the web. An example simulation can be found at http://www.yousimul8.com/watch.php?x=4d5005d769d31.

If you have a look at what's going with this page, when you press play it loads an iframe in and the simulation is shown there.

I've been speaking to a customer who has been having difficulty using the site. When they open a simulation, only the border of the iframe is shown and nothing else happens. This is using IE10. The problem disappears when compatibility view is turned on.

I cannot replicate this issue with IE10 no matter how hard I try. The customer's IT is outsourced so they cannot access the settings, developer tools or console in IE.

So the question is this: What configuration of the client's machines could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force to the rendering of the page to latest version of IE, overriding the automatic compatibility view, try to use the [Meta Tag Compatibility View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Have a look [to this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) post.

Comment: Thanks Giacomo. It was the 'EmulateIE7' option that worked for me in the end but I didn't know about this meta tag behavior so your answer put me on track and I found the solution in the question you linked to.